# Red Black Tree - return all the values greater than X in sorted order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, red-black-tree

I really need this feature in my project. Namely, I have a Red Black Tree and I need to write a function to return all the values higher than X in the sorted order.

Example:

Given the following RBT

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Red-black_tree_example.svg/500px-Red-black_tree_example.svg.png

function greater(6) should return [ 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 22, 25, 27]

function greater(11) should return [13, 15, 17, 22, 25, 27]

Any suggestion ?  What is the recursion to do it given the fact that I already have found the node X ?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? A working implementation of RBT? Write one yourself, and when it doesn't work, come back with a concrete problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an inorder traversal on the tree, when you find a value greater than the given value push it to the result array and return it back.

#### Updated for optimisation:

> We don't have to check the left subtree of the current node if the value of the current node is < than the target boundary value. Only check the left subtree if its value is >= target boundary value.

Here is the working example with the Javascript code.

```js
/**
 * Function to create a tree node with null left and right child
 * @param {Number} val
 * @return {Node} tree node
 * */
function Node(val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}
// Constructing the tree
const root = new Node(13);
root.left = new Node(8);
root.left.left = new Node(1);
root.left.left.right = new Node(6);
root.left.right = new Node(11);
root.right = new Node(17);
root.right.left = new Node(15);
root.right.right = new Node(25);
root.right.right.left = new Node(22);
root.right.right.right = new Node(27);

/**
 * In-order traversal of a  binary tree.
 * While processing the current node, we will check and push the value to result array
 * @param {Node} node
 * @param {Number} contraint value
 * @param {Number[]} result array
 * @return {Void}
 * */
function inorder(node, val, result) {
  if (node == null) return;
   /** 
   * We don't have to check the left subtree of the current node if the value 
   * of the current node is < than target boundary value. Only check left
   * subtree if its value is >= target boundary value.
   * */
  if(node.value >= val) {
      inorder(node.left, val, result);
  }
  
  if (node.value > val) {
    result.push(node.value);
  }
  inorder(node.right, val, result);
}

/**
 * @param {Node} root
 * @param {Number} value
 * @return {Number[]} result
 * */
function getValuesAfter(root, value) {
  const result = new Array();
  inorder(root, value, result);
  return result;
}

console.log("Sorted values after 6:");
const result6 = getValuesAfter(root, 6);
console.log(result6.join(', '));

console.log("Sorted values after 11:");
const result11 = getValuesAfter(root, 11);
console.log(result11.join(', '));



console.log("Sorted values after 22:");
const result22 = getValuesAfter(root, 22);
console.log(result22.join(', '));
```

Comment: Sure, Updated the answer with the working code snippet.

Comment: I tested again the code. I have a question. If I do getValuesAfter(22) it will print only 3 elements, but it will go through through the entire tree. I was thinking the getValuesAfter is optimized and it will have a log n and not an O(N). Is it possible to do it more optimized ?

Comment: Yes, we can do that by updating the inorder traversal algorithm.  We don't have to check the left subtree of the current node if the value of the current node is < than the target boundary value. Only check the left subtree if its value is >= target boundary value. I have updated the code sample with this approach.

Comment: In that way for `getValuesAfter(22)` we will be traversing through the following nodes =>
 13, 17, 25, 22, 27

Comment: Also if the tree is not going to be modified every time we call `getValuesAfter` function we can **memorize** the result for each node in a `Map` so that we can access the result in O(1) for some cases.